# Boost asio UDP sockets block when sending to non-existing targets

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, udp, asio

How can I prevent boost asio from blocking when sending UDP packets to non-existant targets?

---

I have a module which sets up the socket like this:

```
boost::asio::ip::udp::socket   socket(io_service, boost::asi::ip::udp::v4() )
boost::asio::ip::edp::endpoint destination;

destination.address(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("192.168.1.62") );
destination.port(13666);
```

Then calls this at 100 Hz:

```
socket.send_to( m_buffer, destination);
```

---

When I was using boost 1.62 (Debian 9), this was working great. I noticed:

- Frequently blocks for a few microseconds while the network device is busy (this is fine).

However, when I upgrade to boost 1.67 (Debian 10) I notice that:

- If UDP endpoint is online (exists), then I get identical behavior to boost 1.62.
- If UDP endpoint is offline, then `send_to` may block for 10-20 milliseconds (this is **NOT** fine).

---

`socket.non_blocking(true)` unfortunately isn't the solution, because that results in too many lost packets when the endpoint does exist (the 2 microsecond delay is within my realtime tolerance).

I don't think `socket.async_send_to(...)` is the solution because I run at 100 Hz and with > 10ms of blocking per iteration, the send queue will continue to grow indefinitely.

Comment: Use the async functions (like e.g. [`async_write`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write.html) or similar)?

Comment: I send at 100 Hz, If I use `async_` functions, then an average delay of >10ms will result in a indefinitely growing queue.

Comment: Hm, `boost::asio::socket_base::do_not_route` looks interesting.  Hypothesis:  Before sending UDP packet to an address which doesn't exist, the networking service needs to decide which network interface to use.  By default, it uses the built-in routing logic of the service to query and resolve the appropriate interface, sending out ICMP packets to routers and and waiting for a response which says "I know where that is".  That can't be resolved so it times out.  This flag will avoid that logic, simply sending on the network interface where the IP/subnet match.   Does that make sense?

Comment: Is it a local (on net, not routed) IP?

Comment: yes,  It's local

Comment: Can you do a packet capture to understand what's going on during these 10 ms ?

Comment: Use `strace` on your binary and `tcpdump` the traffic at the same time. With `strace` you should be able to pinpoint which syscall hangs for 10-20 ms which is a lot and go from there. Finally, it's irrelevant whether you go async or sync as both of them are implemented using the same syscalls.